# MVC local dev The underlying provider failed on open - Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON' in Firefox only

Tags: sql-server, authentication, iis, asp.net-mvc-4

I've noticed a number of similar topics but none of them either solved the issue or had quite the same circumstances so I figured I'd post the issue and then answer it to help anybody else.

IE/Chrome had no issue but in Firefox when accessing pages of my mvc intranet project running locally to dev test those pages that access my sql database, I would get the error 'The underlying provider failed on Open' which with debugging it told me 'Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.

In most cases this seems to not be browser specific and was generally an issue with the connection string to the db, I had found a perfect question which listed most of the likely issues but can't find it now so if I do I'll link that.

As far as I could see my issue was to do with double hopping from my machine to iis then to the database and it lost my credentials in firefox at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While most solutions to this indicated that you needed to set  or add Integrated Security=True; to the connection string among other possible solutions.

I first found that if I set impersonate to true and passed in my own domain username and password that it fixed it but this was a bad solution as it required me to store my details.

The actual solution which solved this particular problem with least possible issues was to set impersonate to false and bam no further issues.

Answer (score -2):

This is a database connection problem, not a browser problem, check that the sql service is opened, check also if your connection string is valid, you can post your code.

Comment: I marked your answer down as it repeats part of what I already included in my question and ignores the fact that it's a browser specific issue.